# SQL Oracle CHECK (invalid relational operator problem)

Tags: sql, oracle

Help! Can't figur it out what's the problem here --> ORA-00920: invalid relational operator.

```
   alter table kund
add constraint kund_persnr_pk primary key(persnr)
add constraint kund_username_uq unique (username)
add constraint kund_kredittyp_ck check(kredittyp 'hög', 'medel', 'låg');
```

Comment: The content of `check` needs to be an expression that's valid in e.g. a `where` clause. What is `kredittyp 'hög', 'medel', 'låg'` meant to do?

Comment: The kredittyp is suppose to include 3 options - hög', 'medel' or 'låg. But it looks like Tim solved this with the "IN".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to check that the `kredittyp` column can have one of three values?

```
ALTER TABLE kund
ADD CONSTRAINT kund_persnr_pk PRIMARY KEY (persnr),
CONSTRAINT kund_username_uq UNIQUE (username),
CONSTRAINT kund_kredittyp_ck CHECK (kredittyp IN ('hög', 'medel', 'låg'));
```